# What is the simplest way to output values of two specific fields from an HTML file?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm fetching the HTML from [this url](https://asunnot.oikotie.fi/myytavat-asunnot/helsinki/15597485). I'm interested in these are two lines:

`<meta name="SAC:price" content="444000">
<meta name="SAC:published" content="2020-03-28 11:06:22">`

I want to extract the content value of those two lines. In this example my desired output is

`[444000, 2020-03-28 11:06:22]`

What is the simplest way to do this? This is what I've tried so far:

```
function myFunction() {
  var url = "https://asunnot.oikotie.fi/myytavat-asunnot/helsinki/15597485"
  var str = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  let r = /ce" content="(\d{6})">|hed" content="(.*)">/g,out=[];     
  let arr = [...str.matchAll(r)]; //[[ce" content="444000">, 444000, null], [hed" content="2020-03-28 11:06:22">, null, 2020-03-28 11:06:22]]
  for(a of arr){
    a.shift();
    (a[0])?out.push(a[0]):out.push(a[1]);
    } 
  Logger.log(out); //[444000, 2020-03-28 11:06:22]
}
```

This seems excessively cumbersome, any better options? I don't mind how it's done (regex or some other way, as long as I can consistently get the content of those two fields in the simplest way possible)

Final solution thanks to Wiktor Stribiżew's contribution:

```
function myFunction() {
  var url = "https://asunnot.oikotie.fi/myytavat-asunnot/helsinki/15597485"
  var str = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  let r = /(?<=ce" content=")\d{6}(?=">)|(?<=hed" content=").*(?=">)/g;     
  let arr = str.match(r);
  Logger.log(arr); //[444000, 2020-03-28 11:06:22]
}
```

Comment: If you want to get rid of nulls and only keep the match values, make sure you only consume what you want to fetch: `let r = /(?<=ce" content=")\d{6}(?=">)|(?<=hed" content=")[^"]*(?=")>/g;`

Comment: That regex only seems to select for 444000, see https://regex101.com/r/rAjZOe/1

Comment: A typo on my end (in `(?=")>`), it must be `let r = /(?<=ce" content=")\d{6}(?=">)|(?<=hed" content=")[^"]*(?=">)/g`

Comment: Thank you, I was unfamiliar with positive lookaheads/lookbehinds. That really simplifies things!

Comment: Note that look-behind support is super useful but not universally supported in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get rid of nulls and only keep the match values, make sure you only consume what you want to fetch:

```
let r = /(?<=ce" content=")\d{6}(?=">)|(?<=hed" content=")[^"]*(?=">)/g;
```

Here, `(?<=ce" content=")` and `(?<=hed" content=")` are *positive lookbehinds* that match a *position* in the string that is immediately *preceded* with some (here, fixed) text and `(?=">)` is a positive lookahead that match a position in the string that is immediately *followed* with some text.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JzrHqb/1)

Then, all you need to get the result array is to call the regex with `String#match`:

```
let arr = str.match(r);
```

See [more about lookarounds here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Answer (score 0):

There is one hack to do it, You can use replace with function to grab the value. Please check.

```js
const data = `<meta name="SAC:habitationType" content="1">
 <meta name="SAC:price" content="444000">
<meta name="SAC:published" content="2020-03-28 11:06:22">
<meta name="SAC:listingType" content="1">`
let matches = []
data.replace(/content="(\d{6}|\d\d\d\d-.+)">/g, (_,m) => {
  matches.push(m)
})
console.log(matches)
```

```css
.as-console-row {color: blue!important}
```

Comment: This *might* be OK for the question, but your regular expression matches input that the OP expression does not. The OP restricts what the "content" attribute value can be based on the contents of the "name" attribute.

Answer (score -1):

You've got a `|` operator.  Only one side will match, and thus the capturing group on the other side will be `null`. The `.matchAll()` operation always includes the values of *all* capturing groups in the regular expression, including those that matched nothing.

The linked example page has its own code apparently that figures out which alternative matched. It's not simply using `.matchAll()` in other words, or it's post-processing the results.

Comment: So is there are any way to snap only those two values with one regex formula? Or there's no way around separating that expression into var re1 = /ce" content="(\d{6})">/; -> matchAll -> extract group and then var re2 = /hed" content="(.*)">/-> matchAll -> extract group ?

Comment: Well you could filter the results after the fact if you don't like the nulls; it's not clear what you really want.

Comment: Check my answer, one hack can be achieved!